# How to display specific row format in HTML, CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create rows of links in html+css, the format of which should look like this:

(Psuedocode)

```
<body class="class_with_minmaxwidth_set_in_css">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="fixed_left_40px"></div>
        <div class="fluid_center_which_changes_with_window_size"></div>
        <div class="fixed_right_40px"></div>
      </div>
      ... repeat more row divs
    </div>
</body>
```

I have tried various combinations of using floats, positions and displays for each of the three divs within, but still am not able to set the right combination. Help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: what do you want it to look like? Create a fiddle with your current html and css and upload a mockup of your desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align `div` elements in a `line`, use `display: inline:block`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="fixed_left_40px"></div>
    <div class="fluid_center_which_changes_with_window_size"></div>
    <div class="fixed_right_40px"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   .row div{
    display: inline-block;

    height: 40px;
}

.fixed_left_40px{
    width: 40px;    
    background: blue;
}

.fixed_right_40px{
    background: red;
    width: 40px;
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RZ79/3/)

Comment: I have to run to work, but if you need some more help feel free to drop a comment.

Comment: That doesn't provide a fluid centre cell like the OP asked for

Comment: @3rror404 What do you mean by that. Edit, now I see. I'll update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`display: table` is perfect for this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8LZ9B/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="fixed">40px</div>
        <div class="fluid">fluid</div>
        <div class="fixed">40px</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.row div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.row div.fixed {
    width: 40px;
}

.row div.fluid {
   background: lightGreen;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.row div {
    display: inline-block;
}

.row .fixed_left_40px {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
}

.row .fixed_right_40px {
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/Bsrur/

Comment: That doesn't provide a fluid centre cell like the OP asked for

Comment: It does it automatically @3rror404. plus the OP does not ask specific for the fluid center cell.

Comment: No it doesn't. Check the width of the centre cell in this updated version of your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Bsrur/1/ . His question mentions a "fluid_center_which_changes_with_window_size"